# Keeping carousel on a website centered in the page after browser resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm in the middle of working on a website, and the homepage is a jquery-based carousel that I took from [here](https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster) and modified heavily for the specific way I needed it to look for the site. The problem is, I've had to manually define the positions of each carousel item to center them properly around a circular background for every screen resolution that the site is viewed on in the CSS, like this:

```
@media (device-width: 1680px) {
    .flipster-carousel .flip-past {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-22%) translateY(-15%) translateZ(0) scale(0.30);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-22%) translateY(-15%) translateZ(0) scale(0.30);
        -o-transform: translateX(-22%) translateY(-15%) translateZ(0) scale(0.30);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-22%) translateY(-15%) translateZ(0) scale(0.30);
        transform: translateX(-22%) translateY(-15%) translateZ(0) scale(0.30);
    }
}
```

I can tell that this definitely isn't the best way to do this, and it's a very hacky method. The big problem that I've discovered with doing it this way is that if the browser window on the computer isn't full screen, the carousel elements will be shifted and off center from the rest of the site. I absolutely have to fix this so that the carousel will stay centered with the rest of the page when the browser window is resized, but I don't even know where to begin with coding that. Can someone point me in the right direction or give me some advice for what to do? The site I'm working on is located [here.](http://lipocircuit.com) Thanks!

Comment: `margin-left/right:auto` on the next parent?

Comment: omg thank you I think that fixed it, I just have to readjust the position for every screen resolution now but that seems like it worked! I can't believe it was that simple

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left/right:auto` fixed it.